# Struct or class type expected error in mql4

Tags: c++, mql4, metatrader4, mql5, metatrader5

I'm working on a MetaTrader indicator using mql4 with the object-oriented programming model. I created a view file and a controller. I get this error:
'drawPairNamesListForex' - Struct or class type expected.
'IndicatorDashboard' - Undeclared identifier.

Here is the controller:

```
int OnInit()
  {
    View IndicatorDashboard = new View();
    ShowHideForexScreenerState=false;
    IndicatorDashboard.ButtonCreate(0,prefix1+"ShowHideForexScreenerState",0,shiftX+boxWidth*2,shiftY,boxWidth*2,boxHeight,CORNER_LEFT_UPPER,"FOREX",fontType,TaillePolice,ShowHide_Button_Text_Color,ShowHide_Button_Color,clrNONE,false,false,false,true);
    EventSetTimer(2);
    return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }

void OnChartEvent(const int id,
                  const long &lparam,
                  const double &dparam,
                  const string &sparam)
  {
  int i = 0;
  string name = "";
  int XIncrimenet = shiftX;
  int YIncriment  = shiftY+(boxHeight*1);
  if(sparam==prefix1+"ShowHideForexScreenerState" && !ShowHideForexScreenerState)
   {
      ShowHideForexScreenerState = true;
      IndicatorDashboard.drawPairNamesListForex();
   }
```

this is the View class where I get the 'drawPairNamesListForex' method from:

```
class View
  {
private:

public:
       void drawPairNamesListForex();
        View();
        ~View();
};

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+


View::View()
  {
  
  }

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+


View::~View()
  {
  
  }

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

void View::drawPairNamesListForex()
{
   int headerNumberInChart = 0;
   int XIncrimenet = shiftX;
   int YIncriement  = shiftY+boxHeight;
   int indiceTablePairs         = 0;
   string pairNameCleaned       = NULL;
   int sizeSuffix               = StringLen(suffixPairs);
   int sizePreffix              = StringLen(prefixForex);
   int sizeAllThePair           = 0;
   int posiitonSuffix           = 0;
 
 for(int i = 0; i < ArraySize(ForexPair); i++ )
   {   
         pairNameCleaned = ForexPair[i];
         if (  sizeSuffix > 0 )  
           {
            sizeAllThePair    = StringLen(pairNameCleaned);
            posiitonSuffix    = StringFind(pairNameCleaned,suffixPairs);
            pairNameCleaned   = StringSubstr(pairNameCleaned,0,posiitonSuffix);
           }
          if ( sizePreffix > 0 )
           {
            sizeAllThePair    = StringLen(pairNameCleaned);
            pairNameCleaned   = StringSubstr(pairNameCleaned,sizePreffix,sizeAllThePair);
           }
         this.ButtonCreate(0,prefixForex+"PairName"+IntegerToString(i),0,shiftX,YIncriement,boxWidth*2,boxHeight,CORNER_LEFT_UPPER,pairNameCleaned,fontType,TaillePolice,textHeaderColor,headerColor,clrNONE,false,false,false,true);
         YIncriement+=boxHeight;       
   }   
}
```

Comment: `IndicatorDashboard` is a *local* variable in `OnInit()`. It dies as soon as that function finishes and is not visible outside of that function.

Comment: I see! How do you suggest to solve it?

Comment: This is my first time working on a c++ project with the oop model.

Comment: I don't know. The bad solution would be to make `IndicatorDashboard` global. Better solution would be designing your program in such a way that this variable can be encapsulated somehow.

Comment: Also, I'm quite sure that `View IndicatorDashboard = new View();` doesn't compile either.

Comment: What is the correct way to create an instance of the class View?

Comment: Simply `View IndicatorDashboard;`. Or, if you really want to allocate it on the heap and you really cannot use smart pointer, `View* IndicatorDashboard = new View();`